# Highlighting selected word in text using RGB

Tags: vba, ms-word

I want to highlight selected word in text using not `wdColor`but by giving the RGB colour.
I wrote something like this, but I have a compile error "Invalid qualifier".

```
Selection.Range.HighlightColorIndex.Color = RGB(255, 192, 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This code works:

```
 With Selection.Font.Shading
        .BackgroundPatternColor = RGB(255, 192, 0)
 End With
```

Comment: Elaborate your answer.

Comment: I was referring to make it more explanatory and depicting, not just a code dump. [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible because Value of Highlight is enum called HighlightColorValues, and it only accepts its 17 values, which are  are described [here]:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/documentformat.openxml.wordprocessing.highlightcolorvalues?view=openxml-2.8.1

I am trying to figure out the mapping of those values to HEX, as I could not find anything over the internet. If I won't I will map them myself and can post them here, though am not sure if this will help you more than being able to properly compare this enum to RGB/hex color.

By the way the answer you posted is not highlighting but shading, which can sometimes act as a replacement, but sometimes causes unwanted effects, like 'highlighting' the whole cell in table instead of just text.